# Loss-epoch curve looks weird. How to improve multiclass classification model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras

I'm training a set of images using MobileNet that would do multiclass classification. After training loss-epoch curve spikes towards the end

I'm not sure how to interpret this, if this is good enough/acceptable? But there are some spikes in the end so I'm assuming it's not good? How to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is a common phenomenon for a peak to appear when the model converges.
This issue can be observed in many CNN or transformer-based classification models, such as the figure in the "ResNet" Paper.

[image: ResNet Loss curve]

You may also notice that many loss curves appear very smooth; this is because they employ 'moving averaging' to present smoother loss curves.

Therefore, I recommend training for more epochs to observe changes in the loss curve or selecting a smaller learning rate. Additionally, you can utilize checkpoints to save the model with the lowest validation loss.